# Property 'x' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<Interface, "x">'. TS2741

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-redux

I am trying to pass some things from redux store to a component with `connect`. This is my code:

Parent:

```
export const MainPage = (
  {
    count,
    handleIncrementClick,
    selectedOfferId,
  }: MainPageProps,
): React.ReactElement => {
  const handleClick = (): Function => handleIncrementClick(count + 1);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 data-testid="FirstH1">{`Selected offer: ${selectedOfferId}`}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="button">
        {`Klikłeś  ${count}  razy`}
      </button>
      <OffersContainer /> {/* It throws the error here */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child:

- Container:

  ```
   const mapStateToProps = (state: globalStateType) => ({
     dataset: state.offersDataSet,
   });

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): FSetSelectedOfferIdInterface => ({
     FSetSelectedOfferId: (
       selectedOfferId: selectedOfferIdType,
     ) => dispatch(setSelectedOfferId(selectedOfferId)),
   });

   export const OffersContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OffersComponent);
  ```
- Component:

  ```
   export const OffersComponent = ({ offersDataSet }: OffersPropsInterface): ReactElement => (
     <>
       {offersDataSet.map(({
         id, firstName, city, price, image, description,
       }): React.ReactElement => (
         <FlexWrapper key={id.$oid}>
           <OfferContainer
             id={id}
             firstName={firstName}
             city={city}
             price={price}
             image={image}
             description={description}
           />
         </FlexWrapper>
       ))}
     </>
   );
  ```

OffersPropsInterface:

```
export interface OffersPropsInterface {
  offersDataSet: OfferPropsInterface[];
}
```

OfferPropsInterface:

```
export interface OfferPropsInterface {
  id: {'$oid': string};
  firstName: string;
  city: string;
  price: number;
  image: string;
  description: string;
}
```

This seems like a simple problem, but for some reason I get this error:

> Property 'offersDataSet' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<OffersPropsInterface, "offersDataSet">'.  TS2741

Why though? I'm not rendering the component, instead I'm rendering the container, which requires only the `offersDataSet` as an array, which is provided through redux. How can I make it so that the `offersDataSet` is mandatory, but only for redux, not for rendering? Or is the problem something entirely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm stupid. I was assigning the redux data to a wrong name. Here:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: globalStateType) => ({
   dataset /* This should've been offersDataSet.*/: state.offersDataSet,
 //^^^ offersDataSet
});
```

Now I know why I need types for everything...